# Passenger "No such file to load" error for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm having a problem with deploying a Rails 3 app to a Passenger/Apache2/RVM server running Ubuntu 11.10.

I'm getting the error:

> A source file that the application requires, is missing.
>
> ...
>
> Error message: No such file to load -- Goal
>
> Exception class: LoadError

Goal is one of my Rails Models.

I've seen a lot of people with a similar error message, but their issues seem to relate to missing bundles/gems  - not model files! Their problems were resolved by ensuring permissions were set up correctly, so to that end I've got:

Apache running as www-data, as is Passenger. RVM is installed as www-data and I've chown'd the entire web app directory to www-data.

I've been wrestling with this for some time now and am really out of ideas - if anyone has any suggestions I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've solved it. Turned out that a work around for a problem with yaml encoded model archives (i.e. an explicit require of Goal) in a completely unrelated Model was causing the error to appear. Looks like it only rears its head in production - probably due to the differences between the class loaders used in development vs. production.

Tough one to find... the stack trace didn't include a reference to where the problem *actually* was!

Answer (score 1):

You might probably have the file structure of your Rails app wrong. Are you sure you have the "goal.rb" file within {your_app_root_url}/app/models/ ?

To me, if I am seeing the error when you view the app in browser, it seems like your rails app and passenger(with apache2) are working fine. The other possibility is you might be looking at wrong app folder which passenger is set up to.

It's hard to tell what's wrong. Please provide more details of how you set up your passenger with your rails app directory. Also it would help if you could show what's inside your app (app structure) and what's inside goal.rb model file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The model is in the standard place. Interestingly, in the meantime I've set RailsEnv to development and it's all sprung in to life - so it's likely a problem in the differences between the two environment config files.